# Scrape a price off a website

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding

I'm trying to scrape a price from a web page using PHP and Regexes. The price will be in the format £123.12 or $123.12 (i.e., pounds or dollars).

I'm loading up the contents using libcurl. The output of which is then going into `preg_match_all`. So it looks a bit like this:

```
$contents = curl_exec($curl);

preg_match_all('/(?:\$|£)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{2})?/', $contents, $matches);
```

So far so simple. The problem is, PHP isn't matching anything at all - even when there are prices on the page. I've narrowed it down to there being a problem with the '£' character - PHP doesn't seem to like it.

I think this might be a charset issue. But whatever I do, I can't seem to get PHP to match it! Anyone have any ideas?

(Edit: I should note if I try using the [Regex Test Tool](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php) using the same regex and page content, it works fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to use \ in front of £

```
preg_match_all('/(\$|\£)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})/', $contents, $matches);
```

I have try this expression with .Net with \£ and it works. I just edited it and removed some ":".
[image]
<sub>(source: [clip2net.com](http://clip2net.com/clip/m12122/1227972904-clip-9kb.png))</sub>

Read my comment about the possibility of Curl giving you bad encoding (comment of this post).

Comment: I have edited the regex and removed few other things. Check the screenshot. Are you sure it's not the way you use the match after the regex?

Comment: I just noticed your edit. If the regex work fine it might be the encoding of the page from the curl that give you some encoding problem with $ and £. You might want to output the curl data to check it.

Comment: Yep, turns out curl was giving encoding ISO-8859-1, which apparently PHP doesn't like. Converting to UTF-8 seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe pound has it's html entity replacement? i think you should try your regexp with some sort of couching program (i.e. match it against fixed text locally).

i'd change my regexp like this: `'/(?:\$|£)\d+(?:\.\d{2})?/'`

Comment: Thanks - I tried saving it locally and it came up with an error when opening the file. If I convert the string to utf8, it works! So I guess I just need to detect the charset.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for simple values.

```
'#(?:\$|\£|\€)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)#'
```

This will not work with thousand separator like 234,343 and 34,454.45.